# Access iOS app documents directory from OS X

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, ipad

I'm working on an iOS app that creates some files and saves it in its documents directory. It would be really helpful for this app if I could create an OS X app that could access that apps documents directory as well as the pictures on the device. I know it's possible because of [this app](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/), but I can't seem to find a way to implement it. The iOS app does need to be approved by apple, but the desktop app doesn't. With these apps I am targeting non-jailbroken iOS 5 devices and OS X Lion. Any ideas on how I could do this?

A few other solutions I am considering:

1. upload the apps documents directory to iCloud and then download it on the desktop
2. upload to dropbox for auto syncing
3. make the desktop app into a server and upload from the app to the desktop over the network

Those are all backup solutions, but it would be great if I could do this without having to depend on the network.

Comment: You'll probably find some pointers in the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579950/accessing-the-iphone-filesystem-from-a-mac-os-x-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at: [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/). It's a library designed just for that. Anyway, all of this is not supported by Apple, as there isn't any public API for accessing the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your device to act as a HTTP server.  There are several 3rd parties libraries that can help you get started.  I personally have used [iPhonrHTTPServer3](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/downloads/detail?name=iPhoneHTTPServer3.zip&can=1&q=) which is based on [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer)?