# How to programmatically access iphone file system on Mac OS X via USB

Tags: iphone, macos, filesystems, usb

I want to access iphone file system via USB like DiskAid or iExplorer programmatically

Which tool or library can I use to do that ?

I have found usbmuxd, libmobiledevice, ... but not clearly understand how to use them

Thanks

Comment: As, iExplorer only shows filesystem of user installed apps for non-jailbroken device and it provides full filesystem access for jailbroken device. It is easy to get full filesystem of jaibroken device. And For non-jailbroken device, you can use libimobiledevice, which provides full access to filesystem of user installed apps

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing the iPhone filesystem from a Mac OS X application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579950/accessing-the-iphone-filesystem-from-a-mac-os-x-application)