# Accessing iOs file system from Windows in C#

Tags: c#, ios, .net, ssh, filesystems

Firstly I tried to access it with SSH, but running an ls command and then getting the output stream takes too much time, and also required packages to be installed on the device.

Is there a way to access a USB connected iOs device file system from Windows any other way? I also read about Xamarin, but as I can see it's only good for developing apps for iOs.

Edit: The possible duplicate question partly solved my answer, however I needed to find a compiled version for Windows (see comments below).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing the iPhone filesystem from a Mac OS X application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579950/accessing-the-iphone-filesystem-from-a-mac-os-x-application)

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Thanks, this http://www.libimobiledevice.org/ looks good. Can you tell me how can I use this with c# with Visual Studio?

Comment: They have a mailing list and API documentation on their site. Did you check them?

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Yes, I've seen that, I just don't know how to include it into the project. I mean I should have dll files, shouldn't I?

Comment: As I understand it, they give a library in source code, from which you can compile an unmanaged DLL and then call your DLL from C# code using P/Invoke.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp I compiled under linux, but that didn't create dlls, just a bunch of .lo files. Maybe I should compile it under windows, but how?

Comment: Of course to get Windows DLL you must compile on Windows. Create new project, add files ... Write to their mailing list if you need assistance.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Thank you for your help, but it seems that is harder than I thought. I found this issue on this topic: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues/24 , which seems to have been solved, and all the instructions are at the bottom of the page along with the compiled binary (which looks pretty fresh, so I think it's good enough for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our company had a lot of trouble with this; at first, we could not find any available C#/.NET library to do this. We ended up writing our own library using external library calls, but it had numerous stability issues and we gave up. Eventually, we found a library that provided a very good code base: [MK.Mobile.Device.Lite](http://mkindustries.github.io/MK.MobileDevice.Lite/)

The documentation is scarce, but the code is quite self-explanatory; the library provides LOTS of functions for accessing iDevices over a USB cable, and the project maintainer stated that network capabilities may become available in the foreseeable future.

We have incorporated this great open source library into many of our applications, and the implementation is quite simple: you register an event that fires when a device is plugged in/unplugged, and you can call your code on those events.

The functions are extensive, allowing code to fetch many different aspects of the device. If you contact them, there is a version of the library that is even more powerful than the free libary; however it is not open source.

Good luck using this library. We have had great success, and have been able to use it in many of our applications.

Note: 
After using this library, we are now affiliated with the group that develops this library.

Comment: You've done a great job writing such text, but you are related to the products to which you post the links here, so you are required by the rules of the community to disclose your affiliation. That's just a friendly advice for now but if you continue, one will flag your messages as spam.

Comment: The documentation is really missing. obc7787 can you please give me a hint on how to start? I don't find where to hook up the evnt you mention.

Comment: Trying to run MobileDeviceLiteDemo in the MK.Mobile.Device.Lite package - An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in MK.MobileDevice.Lite.dll